# jQuery CSS Positioning

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/mretchin/JEVuX/40/

That's my code.  I'm trying to make an input box that takes a number, using the .val() method, and positions the red box with that value with the .css() method.  I can't figure it out...?  As lame as this sounds, when I wrote it a few hours ago and debugged it in IE, it worked, but when I got home, the same jsfiddle link wasn't functioning on Chrome.  Is it just my browser?  The code will accept 0 as an attribute, but not anything else.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.val()` returns a string. One way to solve this--as others here have noted--is by appending `px` to the end of the string. However, you can instead pass a true numeric value to the `.css()` method, in which case you don't need to append `px`. I prefer this way of doing it, as it requires less code and leaves things more easily readable.

All you need to do is add a plus sign before `$(this).val()` in order to coerce it into a number:

`var value = +$(this).val()`

And then the rest of your code will work fine.

Beyond this specific case, not needing to append `px` is useful to know because you'll often be grabbing CSS values using methods like `.width()`, which automatically return a number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the unit of measurement:

```
$("div").css("left", value + "px");
$("div").css("top", value + "px");
```

Either this or you write `px` in the input itself. Both of these have been tested in Chrome.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JEVuX/42/).

Comment: I believe IE automatically interprets positions as pixels while Chrome needs the unit in the value. I'll check up on that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the units for the `top` and `left` CSS properties ("px", "em", etc).

E.g. I changed your code to:

```
$("#text").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("p").text(value);
    $("div").css({
        left: value + 'px',
        top: value + 'px'
    });
}).keyup();​
```

and [it worked](http://jsfiddle.net/3Khdk/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the value is a string , adding 'px' makes the string into a recognizable css value, but jQuery will also take the css values as a number.

http://jsfiddle.net/JEVuX/51/

Comment: Try to also include the relevant code in your answer as well, it is discouraged to just post a jsFiddle link as either a question or an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dear when you are working with CSS you need to pass PX with the value.

```
$("#text").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val(); 
      $("p").text(value);
      $("div").css("left", value+"px");
      $("div").css("top", value+"px");
    }).keyup();​
```

See this
http://jsfiddle.net/JEVuX/86/